# Y axis values merging with candles in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

Hello every one I am trying to make a separator between y-axis and candles but not able to achieve it. I have highlighted the area which I want to fix with yellow. I am not sure if it's even possible. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is JsFiddle Link:
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/)

**Here is the script**

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        // split the data set into ohlc and volume
        var ohlc = [],
            volume = [],
            dataLength = data.length,
            // set the allowed units for data grouping
            groupingUnits = [[
                'week',                         // unit name
                [1]                             // allowed multiples
            ], [
                'month',
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
            ]],

            i = 0;

        for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
            ohlc.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][1], // open
                data[i][2], // high
                data[i][3], // low
                data[i][4] // close
            ]);

            volume.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][5] // the volume
            ]);
        }


        // create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Historical'
            },

            yAxis: [{
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'OHLC'
                },
                height: '60%',
                lineWidth: 2
            }, {
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Volume'
                },
                top: '65%',
                height: '35%',
                offset: 0,
                lineWidth: 2
            }],

            series: [{
                type: 'candlestick',
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: ohlc,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: volume,
                yAxis: 1,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

[image: Chart Image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`yAxis.offset`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.offset). With this param you can shift the axis further/closer to the plot area. For example:

```
  yAxis: [{
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      x: -3
    },
    title: {
      text: 'OHLC'
    },
    height: '60%',
    lineWidth: 2,
    offset: 20 //new value
  }, {
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      x: -3
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Volume'
    },
    top: '65%',
    height: '35%',
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 2
  }],
```

You can also play with [`yAxis.labels`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.labels) placements and [`yAxis.title`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.title) placements.

You would have to play around with it to find your perfect fit, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

you have set your labels at x:-3 so those are merging in chart.Instead position them as

```
labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: 20
            }
```

See [Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/wyg7ynL5/)